# Adding EditText to a layout in android with for-loop

Tags: java, android, layout, android-edittext

let me introduce you to my issue:

I have just begun with programming for android.
Now I want to create a little app that asks for the amount of players and then a new screen pops up with as many as EditText fields as the amount of players.

Example: I type in the amount of players (4), then I press send, the next screen is filled with 4 EditText fields asking for the players names.

Here's the code:

Method that asks for the amount of players:

```
    public void gaVerder (View view){
    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NamenPersonen.class);

    String aantal = e.getText().toString();
    i.putExtra("aantal", aantal);

    startActivity(i);
}
```

Method that delivers the EditText fields:

```
LinearLayout ll;
EditText editText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent intent = getIntent();

    int aantal = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("aantal"));


    List<EditText> myList = new ArrayList<EditText>();

    EditText myEt1 = new EditText(this);
    myEt1.setHint("Geef uw naam in.");
    myList.add(myEt1);


    for(int i=0;i<aantal;i++)
    {
        editText = new EditText(this);
        editText.setHint("Geef een naam in");


        ll.addView(editText);
    }


    setupActionBar();
    setContentView(R.layout.namenpersonenxml);
}
```

It's the for-loop part and adding it to the lay-out that isn't working. Also I can't figure out how to debug it, I'm used to debugging Java applications in Netbeans (for android I'm using Eclipse).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to initialize `LinearLayout ll`.

```
 LinearLayout ll;
 EditText editText;
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.namenpersonenxml);
 ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearlayout);
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 int aantal = Integer.parseInt(intent.getStringExtra("aantal"));
 for(int i=0;i<aantal;i++)
 {
    editText = new EditText(this);
    editText.setHint("Geef een naam in");
    ll.addView(editText);
 }
```

Comment: Allright, thanks! Tried so many things, and once again a simple line of code does it! Unbelievable :p

Thanks guys! It is working now.

Comment: @user3103015 no prble,. glad to help. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to initialize your `LinearLayout` in which you're adding your EditTexts. At the moment, the program doesn't know which layout you would like to add your views to. So, in your `onCreate()` method, you should add the following code:

```
ll = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.'nameOfYourLayout');
```