# How to show exact amount of Views?

Tags: android

Let I have some number `n`. It can be equal to any integer number ranged between 2 and 15,for example. And according to this number, I need to show `n` `TextView's`(or`Buttons`). I need this concept for creating kind of `4 pic 1 word` quiz game. As you know, in this game , if secret word is banana,then app create 6 places for each letter. And my question is what kind of concepts to use in order to solve this problem? My idea for solution was following: creating some view and add to this view a `TextView` n times. But I don't think that it is right way to do that. Can you tell me what I have to use in order to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

Loads of ways to achieve this:

1. You couid just create the placeholders you want in an XML Layout, I would of thought EditText with maxLength=1 and then use .setVisibility to show the ones you need depending on question;
2. You could use a loop to generate the number of elements you want. See 
   [here for code example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21554985/adding-edittext-to-a-layout-in-android-with-for-loop)